# Using OAuth retrieve access token without redirecting to a webpage

Tags: api, google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth

I had written a java program which uses client id and client secret for authentication. When i run my program it gives an url and when i go to that url it gives me access token. How can i programatically get the access token without using a browser?

My code:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.DirectoryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Users;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DirectoryCommandLine {

  private static String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
  private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

  private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))
        .setAccessType("online")
        .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    System.out.println("Enter authorization code:");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();

    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

    // Create a new authorized API client
    Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("DirectoryCommandLine")
        .build();

    List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    Directory.Users.List request = service.users().list().setCustomer("my_customer");

    // Get all users
    do {
      try {
        Users currentPage = request.execute();
        allUsers.addAll(currentPage.getUsers());
        request.setPageToken(currentPage.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0 );

    // Print all users
    for (User currentUser : allUsers) {
      System.out.println(currentUser.getPrimaryEmail());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use a browser to get user's authorization, but you only have to do it exactly once if you store your refresh token securely.
What's your scenario? You can use embedded browser in mobile, and get the authorization code automatically.

Comment: I have used the browser with redirect uri for my web server. I got the access token using request.getparameter() function.